# Edification is to knowledge as _____ification is to food

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a good possibility I'm just crazy, but I wanted to use a word in a sentence the other day that I could not find in the depths of my memory.  If it exists, it ends in -ification, and means something like "the giving of food/nourishment" in the same way that edification means loosely the giving of knowledge.

Any ideas?

Comment: No, I thought that might be it too, but the meaning I'm thinking of is more along the lines of adding food to a person, rather than adding nutrients to food.

Comment: So try "nutrition". And quit obsessing on finding an "-ification" word.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for ***alimentation***.

> - feeding, being fed; the provision of food and other necessities. [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alimentation)
> - The action or process of being nourished by or of ingesting and digesting food; the action or process of providing food or nutrients; nourishment; nutrition. [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5049?rskey=ihwB97&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Note: It is not *-ification* but *-tion* word. A common alternative would be *feeding*.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst both digestion and metabolism fit the bill well (since you mention `along the lines of adding food to a person`), the rhyming word could be *assimilation*:

> [**assimilation**](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Assimilation). The conversion of nutriment into a useable form (e.g. liquid or solid) that is incorporated into the tissues and organs following the processes of digestion.

I couldn't find an exact word ending with *ification* in a google search, but if you keep searching in Thesaurus, etc. you might be able to find it.